# Dapper: How to get value of query result in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

I am using Dapper to get column value from database in Entity Framework Core like this:

```
var query = await DbConnection.QueryAsync("SELECT AttachmentId FROM dbo.SystemSettings ");

var attachment = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

This code returns

```
{{ DapperRow, AttachmentId = '10' }}
```

How could I get the value of `AttachmentId` which is 10 to use it in the next query

```
DbConnection.QueryAsync<Attachment>("SELECT * FROM dbo.Attachment WHERE Id = @Id", ???);
```

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM dbo.Attachment WHERE Id IN (SELECT AttachmentId FROM dbo.SystemSettings)"`

Comment: @Fabio I think that your idea worths an answer.

Comment: Entity Framework Code **isn't** a database - it's a *database access* technology - like Dapper. From the looks of your code, your database is really **SQL Server** and this question has **absolutely nothing** to do with EF Core ....

Answer (score 3):

to keep with the 2-query theme in the question:

```cs
Int id = query.AttachmentId;
var objs = DbConnection.QueryAsync<Attachment>("SELECT * FROM dbo.Attachment WHERE Id = @Id", new { id });
```

Note that when reading a single column, it may be preferable to use `QueryAsync<int>` or similar, rather than the `dynamic` API.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Fabio for your answer :

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Attachment 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AttachmentId FROM dbo.SystemSettings)
```